# v-if inside v-for showing last element in array

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to `Vue` and having a hard time nesting a `v-if` inside a `v-for`. Everything renders but `{{row.id}}` (inside my `v-if`) is showing the *last* element in my array instead of the *selected* one. The function work fine as I pass `row` as an argument. I'm assuming I have to do something similar here but I can't find an example or explanation in the docs.

Is there a way to pass the entire array to my modal template or do I have to structure this differently?

```
<tr v-for="row in rows">
   <td><img v-bind:src="row.image" height="180" width="130"></td>
   <td>{{row.title}}</td>
   <td>{{row.platform}}</td>
   <td>
      <button id="edit"><img v-on:click="onClickEdit(row)" @click="showModal = true" src='images/edit.png' height='30' width='30'></button>          
      <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
         <h3 slot="header">{{row.id}}</h3>
      </modal>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that each row has a modal. It's not that the modal is showing the last element only, it's that when `showModal` is true, all modals is displayed, the last modal is on top and the other modals are below it.

quickest way to make this work is to set `showModal` to the `row.id`

```
@click="showModal = row.id"
```

and for the modal, use `row.id` for the `v-if`

```
<modal v-if="showModal === row.id" @close="showModal = false">
```

Comment: Awesome, that works and explains my confusion. Thanks!